# How to convert an image from one format to another with Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have to write an application for image processing in python.
Does anyone know how to convert the file type of an image from JPEG to TIFF?

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and which OS/version?

Answer (score 32):

Check out the [Python Image Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). See this [tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm), the PIL is quite easy to use.

[Supported image formats](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/formats.html).

To do the conversion you open the image and then save it with the new extension (which PIL uses to determine what format to use for saving).

```
import Image
im = Image.open('test.jpg')
im.save('test.tiff')  # or 'test.tif'
```

Note that the official distribution does not support Python 3.x (yet?), however, at least under Windows there's an [unofficial version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) available that works with v 3.x.

Comment: The original PIL project has been forked and ported to Python 3: [Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/).

Comment: For python3 after installing `pillow`  it's  `from PIL import Image`

Answer (score 15):

Use the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.jpeg')
img.save('image.tiff')
```

Ref: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Comment: Use `img.convert()` before saving to avoid any errors in file conversion

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) ? It can support many image file format.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use OpenCV (cv2) to convert them like:

```
import os
import cv2

path = r"D:\Folder"
i=0
for x in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(r"{}\{}".format(path,x))
    cv2.imwrite(r'{}\{}.png'.format(path,i),image)
    i+=1
```

(replace png with whatever extension you want, in your case .tiff)