# how to convert jpeg to tiff file in python

Tags: python, image, processing

Is there any way to convert .jpeg to .tiff file?

If yes, then how to do that?

There are many library in Python that can convert file from one format to another.

But, I have not found anything for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137120/format-conversion-of-an-image-in-python)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('yourImg.jpg')
im.save("pathToSave/hello.tiff", 'TIFF')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [OpenCV docs for functions used for image and video reading and writing](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) `imread` does support JPEG files and `imwrite` can save TIFF files, though with some limitations:

> Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIL (Python Imaging Library)](https://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for this:

```
import Image
im = Image.open('test.jpg')
im.save('test.tiff')  # or 'test.tif'
```

Also, this was the first result for your problem on Google, make sure you google extensively first.