# Bokeh - save plot as svg (ValueError: OutputDocumentFor expects a sequence of Models)

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, tiff, bokehjs

I made a plot in Bokeh but when I try to export it as a svg file I get the following error: OutputDocumentFor expects a sequence of Models.

My code is:

```
# plot 2D histogram

def plot_hist(ch1, ch2, ch1_name='G3BP1', ch2_name='Nucleocapsid'):
    '''Plot a 2D histogram from two channels'''
    # get histogram data
    df_hist = pd.DataFrame({ch1_name: ch1.ravel(), ch2_name: ch2.ravel()})
    df_hist = df_hist.groupby(df_hist.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')
    df_hist['log count'] = np.log10(df_hist['count'])

    # make the plot
    return hv.VLine(10).opts(apply_ranges=True, line_width=2, color = 'black', line_dash = 'dashed') * hv.HLine(10).opts(apply_ranges=True, line_width=2, color = 'black', line_dash = 'dashed')*hv.Points(
        data=df_hist, kdims=['G3BP1', 'Nucleocapsid'], vdims=['log count'],
    ).opts(
        size=10,
        cmap='magma',
        color='log count',
        colorbar=True,
        colorbar_opts={"title": "log₁₀ count"},
        frame_height=500,
        frame_width=500,
        padding=0.05,
        xlabel='G3BP1',
        ylabel='Nucleocapsid',
        fontsize=15,        
    )

# make ROI mask
roi1_nt = (single_cell_roi_rCh[1] > 0) | (single_cell_roi_gCh[1] > 0)
roi1_nt = skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(roi1_nt, min_size=3)



hv.renderer('bokeh').theme = 'caliber'

plot=plot_hist(im_r[roi1_nt], im_g[roi1_nt])

from bokeh.io import export_svgs
plot.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(plot, filename = "plot.svg")
```

Is there eventually a way to transform the png file saved from this plot in a tiff file with Geotiff?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In your code I don't find any hint for the mentioned `png`. Can you please explain this part in more detail?

Comment: Just noting that if the OP wants PNG output they would need to use `export_png` instead.

Comment: @mosc9575 it's possible to save the png file directly from the interactive plot once plotted. But I cannot change the file type to svg or directly save it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `holoviews` to create the figure in your function `plot_hist()`. This is not bokeh `object`.

Please try to call `hv.render()` to get the underlying bokeh figure.

The lines below should create a svg file.

```
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.io import export_svgs

plot = plot_hist(im_r[roi1_nt], im_g[roi1_nt])
plot = hv.render(plot)
plot.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(plot, filename = "plot.svg")
```

**Edit**

As @bigreddot metioned, `bokeh` also has a `export_png()` tool. In this case the code shhould look like below.

```
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.io import export_png

plot = plot_hist(im_r[roi1_nt], im_g[roi1_nt])
plot = hv.render(plot)
export_png(plot, filename = "plot.png")
```

If your goal is to generate an "tiff" file from "png", you can follow the solution from this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137120/how-to-convert-an-image-from-one-format-to-another-with-python).

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('plot.png')
img.save('image.tiff')
```

If the png has an alpha value, this could bring some problems. In this case, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107694/opening-png-with-pil-pillow) about open a png in Pillow.